# Unchecking RadioButton's - alternative method

Tags: android, widget, radio-button

Is there any possible way to uncheck a RadioButton by cliking on the checked RadioButton?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton1;
RadioButton radioButton2;
RadioButton radioButton3;

boolean hack = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
    radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r1);
    radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r2);
    radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r3);

    OnClickListener radioClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (v.getId() == radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() && hack)
            {
                radioGroup.clearCheck();
            }
            else
            {
                hack = true;
            }
        }
    };

    OnCheckedChangeListener radioCheckChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            hack = false;
        }
    };

    radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioCheckChangeListener);
    radioButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioCheckChangeListener);
    radioButton3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioCheckChangeListener);

    radioButton1.setOnClickListener(radioClickListener);
    radioButton2.setOnClickListener(radioClickListener);
    radioButton3.setOnClickListener(radioClickListener);

}
```

Ok now i have updated it. This should work Philipz

Comment: Alright man, ill test it later, really appreciate your answer, thanks!

Comment: Hey man, it never checks the RadioButton, cause it's checking and after that unchecking, so the final state is unchecked! :/

Comment: Yes Philipz is tested it and found it the way yout told. However i managed to make it work with the  help of a boolean.. will update the answer in a few moments.

Comment: @Philipz updated the code. This is a simple workaround which works well

Comment: @Varun, This solution is not working for me :( 
Problem: If i click unchecked button first time it will be checked, then i click once again it is unchecked But, if i try to click then it  is not checked.

Comment: try this . https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/deselectable-radio-button/blob/master/res/layout/demo.xml