# Want to Unchecked both RadioButton in RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unchecking RadioButton’s - alternative method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390804/unchecking-radiobuttons-alternative-method)

Scenario is I have 2 radiobuttons in radiogroup [Example- Geneder Selection],

Now when user click on same checked radiobutton then it will be unchecked
means after click both radiobutton are unchecked.

Sequence of Events is 
First onCheckedChanged called 
Second OnClick called

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390804/unchecking-radiobuttons-alternative-method

Comment: simple don't use `RadioGroup` if you want `Radiobutton` to work  independently.

Comment: You might want to see a previous answer of mine. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390804/unchecking-radiobuttons-alternative-method

Comment: `RadioButton`'s are not meant for this, Best is to use a `Spinner`, with nothing selected at first.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/) Example. In that they are same using radio group and two button name with Male -Female.

You Definitively get Success.